# How to make one radiobutton as selected in Custom Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, custom-adapter

I am stuck in a situation where I am using a custom spinner , in which I want a radio button and a text. In this I want just a single radio button should be selected, but when moving on other radio button, last radio button remain selected.

Here is my main Xml File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_lang"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Item file for Custom SPinner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_lang_box"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:text="Hindi"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Well, this is my MainActivity file, in which I had set the adapter.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    String[] country = { "Select Language","French", "Hindi", "Japanese" };
    private Spinner spinnerLanguage;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_lang);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        CustomArrayAdapter customAdapter=new CustomArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),country);
        spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);





        //Creating the ArrayAdapter instance having the country list
        /*ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,country);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
        spinnerLanguage.setAdapter(aa);*/


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
        if (pos == 1) {

            Locale myLocale = new Locale("fr");
            Resources res = getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(refresh);
            finish();


        } else if (pos == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "this is from 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Locale myLocale = new Locale("hi");
            Resources res = getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(refresh);
            finish();


        } else if (pos == 3) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "this is from 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            Locale myLocale = new Locale("ja");
            Resources res = getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            conf.locale = myLocale;
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(refresh);
            finish();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

And this is my Adapter file..
package com.rightarrows.language_change;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by tapes on 5/21/2018.
 */

public class CustomArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;

    String[] countryNames;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] countryNames) {
        this.context = applicationContext;

        this.countryNames = countryNames;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countryNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.dialog_item_list, null);

        TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_lang_box);

        names.setText(countryNames[i]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your CustomArrayAdapter class you should save position of the last selected item. use `setCheck(true);` for that item only and `setCheck(false);` for others. like this:

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;

    String[] countryNames;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    private int last_checked;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] countryNames) {
        this.context = applicationContext;

        this.countryNames = countryNames;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return countryNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.dialog_test, null);

        TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_lang_box);
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_);

        names.setText(countryNames[i]);
        if (i == last_checked) {
            radioButton.setChecked(true);
        } else
            radioButton.setChecked(false);

        radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                last_checked = i;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked for me. But When I am tapping on any of the radio buttons, my actions are not performing accordingly, as in main activity, where I had set some events for Spinner Items.  Can you help me out with that..?

Comment: the problem is with the radioButton.